# Bessel Function Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am trying (with no luck) to integrate this pdf that has a Bessel function within it...

```
f = (-1 + n)*n*Integrate[(1/(\[Rho]*Subscript[x, 1]*(w + Subscript[x, 1])))*E^((-(\[Lambda] + \[Mu]))*Subscript[x, 1] - (\[Lambda] + \[Mu])*(w + Subscript[x, 1]))*
 BesselI[1, 2*Sqrt[\[Lambda]*\[Mu]]*Subscript[x, 1]]*BesselI[1, 2*Sqrt[\[Lambda]*\[Mu]]*(w + Subscript[x, 1])]*
 (-Integrate[(E^((-\[Lambda] - \[Mu])*u)*BesselI[1, 2*Sqrt[\[Lambda]*\[Mu]]*u])/(Sqrt[\[Rho]]*u), {u, 0, Subscript[x, 1]}] + 
   Integrate[(E^((-\[Lambda] - \[Mu])*v)*BesselI[1, 2*Sqrt[\[Lambda]*\[Mu]]*v])/(Sqrt[\[Rho]]*v), {v, 0, w}])^(-2 + n), {Subscript[x, 1], 0, Infinity}]
```

Once I have the pdf, to compute the mean, the following has to be done...

```
 EX = NIntegrate[w fw/. {\[Lambda] -> 0.5, \[Mu] -> 1.0, \[Rho] -> 0.5, n -> 5}, {w, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

Does anyone know how to numerically integrate this?

I think the problem has to do with the terms $(w + x_1)$ in the integral - I've integrated similar Bessel function but they did not have that - they only had 1 term (e.g., $x_1$ or $x_2$ but NOT $x_1 + w$)

I thought about doing a change of variable, but I don't think that is going to matter very much.

Comment: You use `Subscript[x, 1]` both as the variable of integration and as part of the bounds for that integration. I believe that you need to deconflict. Also recommend that you use an indexed variable rather than a subscript. Please post code in `Raw InputForm` rather than the box structure.

Comment: Yes - I already did that - I apologize for not posting that code- I changed it to another variable - When I did this, it ran for a while and nothing happened - I also used NIntegrate as well. All this is trying to compute is the range of random variable $R$=$X_n$ - $X_1$. I already know the answer - I'm just trying to verify it via numerical integration...